# Subsetting all Rows with NA (Missing Value) in any of the columns

Tags: r, na

I've a dataset (teleco) with 3000 obs and there are many (332) missing value (NA)s in it. When i try to subset all the missing values into another dataframe, I strangely endup with 3745 obs.

```
clean = na.omit(teleco)
new = teleco[is.na(teleco[1:19])==TRUE, ]
```

clean - 2668 obs of 19 vars

new - 3745 obs of 19 vars

teleco - 3000 obs of 19 vars

I'm sure that i'm doing something wrong. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we need to subset rows having at least one `NA`, we can create an index using `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`is.na(teleco)`), and convert that to a logical vector (`!=0`).

```
teleco[rowSums(is.na(teleco))!=0,]
```

Or we can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to create a logical vector.

```
teleco[apply(is.na(teleco), 1, any),]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
teleco <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:10), 20*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer @akrun's solution, but here's an alternative that should give the same result:

```
teleco[unique(which(is.na(teleco), arr.ind=T)[,1]),]
```

The idea is to extract the row numbers with an `NA` using `which()` combined with the option `arr.ind=TRUE`. Since we're not interested in the information on which columns contain an `NA`, we select only the first value of the output provided by `which()` with `[,1]`.

Comment: I don't know why but your code extracts 3745 obs. like i posted in the question.

Comment: I think I have corrected this now by using `unique()`. Maybe you want to try again? If it is a valid alternative I'd rather keep it.

Comment: Perfect - new3 = teleco[unique(which(is.na(teleco), arr.ind=T)[,1]),] this worked!